# Grails subflow restarting to first state

Tags: spring-webflow, grails-2.0

I have a flow that uses a subflow. Something like:

*Initial State -> Subflow -> Next state*

When I'm in the Subflow, I can go back and forward, even return to the 'Initial state' without any problem. However, once I'm out of the subflow and in the 'Next state', any attempt to go back send me directly to the 'Initial State' not to the last step of the subflow.

Any thoughts about that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Find the problem. The 'Next state' was the last state, this is why the flow was being restarted.